# Generate a day date according to existing month+year+daydiff

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

I got a table with these 5 columns:

```
StartMonth, StartYear, EndMonth, EndYear, DaysBetween
```

I don't have the day of these dates and that's what I?m trying to generate.

For example:

```
12     2008  1  2009         8
```

I want to create a **random** date (start date and end date , format as dd/mm/yyyy) which will include the **day** and will make scene upon the data I have under **days between**

E.g., if I know that I got 8 days (`DaysBetween`) and the `startmonth` is 12, the date **must be**
from 24/12/2008 cause if I add 8 days I get the `EndMonth` (1/2009)

If I would choose the date 2/12/2008 I would get 10/12/2008 and its not good cause the month is still 12.... and I need 1 (2009)

How can I generate valid dates ?

Comment: sorry, may i know what is your input parameter(s)?

Comment: and what is the purpose of generate a random date?

Answer (score 0):

You need to parts to solve this:

1. Create a random value between 1 and the `DaysBetween`
2. Use the DateAdd function to pick a date X days before the first of the next month (X being the value from the previous part).

To create a random value try something like this:

```
SELECT Cast((  DAYSBETWEEN   ) * Rand(Cast(Newid() AS VARBINARY)) + 1 
            AS 
                   TINYINT) AS 'randomNumber' 
FROM   TABLE
```

Then add the dateadd function:

```
SELECT Dateadd(DD, Cast(( DAYSBETWEEN  ) * Rand(Cast(Newid() AS 
                                                                VARBINARY)) 
                               + 1 AS 
                                           TINYINT), Dateadd(MONTH, 1, 
                                                     Cast( 
              Cast(STARTMONT AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-01-' 
              + Cast(@StartYear AS VARCHAR(4)) AS DATE))) 
FROM   TABLE
```

Comment: Isn't it redundant to use both `RAND` and `NEWID()`? `RAND()` alone would do the same. Also `DAYSBETWEEN + 1 - 1`? That whole first expression could have just been `SELECT CAST(DAYSBETWEEN * Rand() + 1 AS TINYINT)`

Comment: RAND() alone will not work in a query! It will return a single random value for all rows. NEWID helps reseed the RAND function for each row.

Comment: Oh yes. Good thinking! I knew there is a reason I am not using RAND but couldn't think of it :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
WITH N(n) AS (
    SELECT a*6+b FROM
    (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5))a(a),
    (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6))b(b)
), T(StartMonth,StartYear,EndMonth,EndYear,DaysBetween) AS (
    SELECT 12, 2008, 1, 2009, 8
)

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, DATEADD (dd, -n, DATEADD (mm, StartMonth, DATEADD (yy, StartYear - 1900, '19000101'))) AS dt
    FROM T
    INNER JOIN N ON DaysBetween >= n
) T
WHERE MONTH (dt) = StartMonth
    AND YEAR (dt) = StartYear
    AND MONTH (DATEADD (dd, DaysBetween, dt)) = EndMonth
    AND YEAR (DATEADD (dd, DaysBetween, dt)) = EndYear
```

Comment: looks very good and i need to adjust it to my data...thank you so much . by the way...i executed your query and i got like 8 lines with 8 possible dates... i need only 1 random date not 8...what i need to change in order to get just 1 row?

Comment: @AviShain Add `SELECT TOP 1` ... and .. `ORDER BY NEWID()` to get 1 random row

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample:

```
WITH CTE_Start AS 
(
   SELECT DATEADD(dd,-(ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % DaysBetween+1),dateadd(mm, (EndYear - 1900) * 12 + EndMonth - 1,0)) StartDate, DaysBetween
   FROM dbo.This5Columns
)
SELECT StartDate, DATEADD(dd,DaysBetween,StartDate) AS EndDate
FROM CTE_Start
```

`ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % DaysBetween+1` 
is used to get random number of days between 1 and DaysBetween,

`dateadd(mm, (EndYear - 1900) * 12 + EndMonth - 1,0)` 
Gets the first date of end month (earliest possible end date)

Then you subtract the two to get your StartDate, and add DaysBetween again to get the EndDate

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b47c0/2)**